# how to hide up button in actionbar

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock

I would like to do an edit mode, in the style of the tablet gmail app.
If the user presses the edit button on the actionbar, than I would like to show him/her an action view, that has a done button on the left side, and a delete button on the right.

I have an example that works without actionbarsherlock here:
https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/donediscard

I would like to stick to actionbarsherlock, for compatibility reasons.

This is the way I solved it in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white));
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.white);

for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
    menu.getItem(i).setVisible(false); }
```

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` does nothing, so I had to set the home icon to a white 1x1 pixel drawable.

I also had to set the background color of the actionbar, as the actionview's background color. If I had not, than the 1x1 home icon would have padding around it, and the original background color would be visible around the white home button.

Anyone got a better solution for this?

edit:
I also had to change the style:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/white</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/white</item>
</style>
```

Also..settings android:homeAsUpIndicator increased my min api level from 8 to 11 which is also an issue.

Answer (score 36):

If you're on API level 14 or above and are not using ActionbarSherlock, this code in `onCreateOptionsMenu` will disable the up button, remove the left caret, and remove the icon:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); // disable the button
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // remove the left caret
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // remove the icon
}
```

Comment: I used your code and its working fine. I am able to apply my logo as home button, but i want to set text also with back button. look like image in link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486908/android-action-bar-home-button-customize . Can you help me out in this?

Comment: This worked for me! I just had to change ```getActionBar()``` to ```getSupportActionBar()```. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there. To hide the icon/logo completely, use [`setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29). The call you're using just removes the little arrow that indicates that the icon acts as an "up" button also.

Comment: setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) does nothing. Oh and now I'm stuck with that stupid little arrow. How the heck do I make it disappear. The code I pasted in the opening post does not work anymore for me \ :

Comment: Oh I got it..updated opening post. I accidently deleted some lines from styles.xml.

Comment: I use my drawable as getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.back_button); after getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);. I want to write text with that. Like in image as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486908/android-action-bar-home-button-customize

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, though its a slight change in the above mentioned solution

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); // disable the button
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // remove the left caret
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // remove the icon
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Though it's an older post, I would like to share an answer which worked for me.

To hide the UP button in actionbar, use the following in OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != 
           getSupportActionBar().hide();
       }
```

To remove the UP button in actionbar, use the following in OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != 
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
       }
```

I hope it will help newbies.