# Android: Action bar home button customize

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, android-actionbaractivity

I am developing an application in which what the need in action bar is shown in image:

[image]

I need to apply back arrow with text and search icon custom from drawable. My API level is from min 13 to 21 max. I searched on Google and found to do this from style.xml as:

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

But its not working.

I also tried :

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_button);
```

This gives me error as :

```
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136): com.demo.example fatal error : android.app.ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at com.demo.example.TabbarActivity.activitySearchView(TabbarActivity.java:225)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at com.demo.example.TabbarActivity.onCreate(TabbarActivity.java:157)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-07 13:40:49.465: E/ACRA(20136):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What i am missing or doing wrong. Please suggest me what should i do to achieve my task.

Comment: WHich android version are you compiling in? are u using support action bar?

Comment: Sorry for giving a non-answer - but did you consider conforming to Android standard UI paradigms and use the built-in action bar way of navigating to application home, rather than inventing something proprietary that kind of rather resembles iOS? Is it absolutely critical that the application customizes the look and feel of such a basic feature?
See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html and http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: As KKd mentioned are you extending your class with ActionBarActivity??? Post more code to help you in better way.

Comment: I am compiling my code on API 19 now.

Comment: Your min SDK version must 18.

Comment: Yes i know that min should 18 but the requirement is from at least 14 API level

Comment: Use custom views in actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

Using AppCompat is better option but still if you dont want to use it, set custom view in actionbar. This might be helpful when you are using custom fonts in text.

See this [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)) for more info.

Like this,

```
LinearLayout customView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_layout, null);
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
getActionBar().setCustomView(customView, params);
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

[setHomeAsUpIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)) was introduced with API level 18, and the device where you are experiencing the crash has a version of android older than 18. To overcome it you can use [appcompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)